# How to call stored procedure taking array using odbc:param_query in Erlang

Tags: stored-procedures, erlang, db2, odbc

I have a stored procedure in db2

```
create type intArray as integer array[100]@

create or replace procedure sum(in numList intArray, out total integer) 
begin 
    declare i, n integer;  

    set n = CARDINALITY(numList);

    set i = 1; 
    set total = 100; 

    while (i <= n) do 
    set total = total + numList[i]; 
    set i = i + 1; 
    end while;    
end@
```

I am trying to call through Erlang odbc:param_query.

```
odbc:param_query(Ref,  "CALL sum (?, ?)", [{sql_integer,[1]}, {sql_integer,out, [1]}]).
```

The above is giving me proper return as

```
{executed,1,[{101}]}
```

But when I pass multiple values as

```
 odbc:param_query(Ref,  "CALL sum (?, ?)", [{sql_integer,[1,2,3,4]}, {sql_integer,out, [1]}]).
```

It is throwing an exception

> exception exit: {badarg,odbc,param_query,'Params'}
>       in function  odbc:decode/1 (odbc.erl, line 894)

Is there any other way to pass a list (Array) to the stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to have an equal amount of arguments in both lists of arguments, meaning add three 1s in your 2nd list or arguments.

```
odbc:param_query(Ref,  "CALL sum (?, ?)", [{sql_integer, [1,2,3,4]}, {sql_integer, out, [1,1,1,1]}]).
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no OBDC data type (at least with a corresponding Erlang one) for a list of integer (see [erlang obdc documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/odbc/databases.html#type)). I don't know how the the final query should look like (the syntax for int array) but I think that you can achieve what you want by creating your query as a string:

`Query = io_lib:format("CALL sum (~p , ~p)",[int_array_syntax([1,2,3,4]),1])`

and then use `odbc:sql_query(Ref, Query)`.