# HOW TO: call stored procedures with Tds Library in Elixir

Tags: stored-procedures, elixir, tds

I get the following error trying to call a stored procedure using the [Tds](https://github.com/livehelpnow/tds) library for Elixir

The stored procedure `get_account` exists and has exactly one parameter `@id`

```
iex(5)>Tds.Connection.query(pid, "get_account",[%Tds.Parameter{name: "@id", value: 1}])                                                        
{:error,
 %Tds.Error{message: nil,
  mssql: %{class: 16, length: 252, line_number: 0, msg_text: "Procedure or function 'get_account' expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied.", number: 201, proc_name: "get_account",
    server_name: "localhost\\SQLEXPRESS", state: 4}}}
iex(6)>
```

Trying this with `Tds.proc(pid, "get_account",[1])` does not work either

Comment: This is probably one of those cases where it's easier to drop down to the Erlang ODBC layer and do what you're trying to do.  See this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929391/how-to-call-stored-procedure-taking-array-using-odbcparam-query-in-erlang) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround:

```
Tds.query(pid, "get_account 1",[])
```

Use this the same way you would pass parameters directly to a stored proc using `EXEC`.

Updated:

This format also works:

```
 params = [
  %Tds.Parameter{name: "@1", value: 100, type: :integer},
  %Tds.Parameter{name: "@2", value: 100, type: :integer},
  %Tds.Parameter{name: "@3", value: <<0 ,0 ,0 ,0>>, type: :binary},
]
  Conn.query(s.db, "save_auth_key @1, @2, @3", params)
```